# My Django app is running after I deployed it

Tags: django, python-3.x, namecheap

The link is Mejoshjones.com it was the passenger app will show what’s wrong with the app. I don’t know where to start for as debugging

This is what I think is wrong

```
from tinymce import HTMLField
ImportError: cannot import name 'HTMLField' from 'tinymce' (/home/powevtec/virtualenv/mejoshjones.com/test/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tinymce/__init__.py)
```

Comment: There is a problem with a module import "from tinymce import HTMLField" inside File "/home/powevtec/mejoshjones.com/test/posts/models.py". It should have been "from tinymce.models import HTMLField" as I can see

Answer (score 3):

This error happens when you fail to import module from the library.

You can try this instead.

```
from tinymce.models import HTMLField
```

As described in the documentation, the error is because HTMLField is a property of the tinymce.models class.

https://github.com/aljosa/django-tinymce